# How to unit test a public method that calls private method and that in turn calls a web service method

Tags: unit-testing, mockito, private-methods

Here's the setup:

```
 public class ClassToTest{

    public void doSomething(ObjectToWorkOn[] objects){
        doPrivateStuff(objects);
    }

    private void doPrivateStuff(ObjectToWorkOn[] objects){
        List<ObjectToWorkOn> validObjects=new ArrayList<ObjectToWorkOn>();
        for(ObjectToWorkOn obj:objects){
           if(obj.isValid())
           validObjects.add(obj);
        }
        SomeWebService ws=new SomeWebService();
        ws.processObjects(validObjects);
    }

 }
```

I need to test the public `doSomething` method to check if invalidObjects are filtered. As you can see it passess the `objects` to the private `doPrivateStuff` method. And that method filters out invalid objects and sends valid ones to a web service method. That web service method does not return anything. So I have no clue as to whether only valid objects were sent to the web service method or not. What do you suggest I do to be able to test this case? I'm using Mockito framework for mocking objects.

Comment: Usually you don't need to unit test a method that is a pass through for another method unless you're doing something else in it (like validating your parameter).  If anything, it would be an integration test.  

If you REALLY want to unit test, override the doPrivateStuff() function and ensure the pass through happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main reason you can't test this method is because you create `SomeWebService` inside your class.

To solve this, you should [inject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) `SomeWebService`.

```
public class ClassToTest{
    private readonly ISomeWebService someWebService;

    public ClassToTest(ISomeWebService someWebService)
    {
        this.someWebService = someWebService;
    }

    public void doSomething(ObjectToWorkOn[] objects){
        doPrivateStuff(objects);
    }

    private void doPrivateStuff(ObjectToWorkOn[] objects){
        List<ObjectToWorkOn> validObjects=new ArrayList<ObjectToWorkOn>();
        for(ObjectToWorkOn obj:objects){
           if(obj.isValid())
           validObjects.add(obj);
        }

        someWebService.processObjects(validObjects);
    }
}
```

Now you can mock your `ISomeWebService` dependency in test and verify that `processObjects` method was called with right arguments

Comment: Yes, Dmitriy, that indeed was the key point. Thanks for the insight.